# Folder copy Linux

Tags: linux

What is the command to copy a folder, and its contents, to a location with the following rules:

Possibility 1:
if the folder exists already, preform a force merge WITHOUT overwriting existing files.

AND do not overwrite existing files

Possibility 2:
If the folder does not exist, create it and copy the contents to the newly created folder

Thanks,
Christopher Peterson

Comment: It is important to understand that possibility-1 has two forms: the existing files may be older or newer compared to your source folder contents. It this matters, you will need to understand the answers below better...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cp <base-target> <base-destination> -r --update`

> -u, --update                 copy only when the SOURCE file is newer
>                                than the destination file or when the
>                                destination file is missing
>
> -R, -r, --recursive          copy directories recursively

Comment: Note: The '`-u`' option **will** over write an existing file that is older than the one being copied. This does not quite follow part of the requirements... check the `--no-clobber` option if that is not what you want.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the --no-clobber option.

```
cp --recursive --no-clobber SOURCE DESTINATION
```

From the man page:

```
-R, -r, --recursive
       copy directories recursively
-n, --no-clobber
       do not overwrite an existing file (overrides a previous -i option)
```

Comment: The first answer by @Michael will not do what you want. If the file in the source directory is newer that the destination file it will overwrite it, so requirement 1 will not be met.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the rsync command

Comment: I see you awarded the answer already, but you may wish to consider the extra features offered by rsync... http://serverfault.com/questions/43014/copying-a-large-directory-tree-locally-cp-or-rsync